# map is loading but can't see the map in Android development

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am learning Android development with Lynda video tutorials.

I am using the Google map API v2, to display a map. I have done all the steps according to the tutorial.

when i try to view the application in my device, the application loads I can see the Google logo but map is not visible. (i see the white background with Google logo at the bottom).

I have added my code and the screenshot. can someone please help me to fix this. thank you..

Screenshot

[image]

My java code..

```
package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 47.60621,
SEATTLE_LNG =-122.33207, 
SYDNEY_LAT = -33.867487,
SYDNEY_LNG = 151.20699, 
NEWYORK_LAT = 40.714353, 
NEWYORK_LNG = -74.005973;
private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return (mMap != null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
        float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}

public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
    hideSoftKeyboard(v);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String location = et.getText().toString();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    double lat = add.getLatitude();
    double lng = add.getLongitude();

    gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);

}

private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

}
```

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="Go" 
        android:onClick="geoLocate"/>
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="292dp"
    android:layout_height="374dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my Manifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission 
            android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission 
            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

        <uses-feature 
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>


                   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


            <meta-data 
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="I Added my Api Key"/>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

can someone please help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Is the api key the one you applied for yourself? Or is it something you copied from the tutorial? In either case, I wouldn't post my api key publicly like you just did.

Comment: Are you using Updated google play service???

Comment: i added my own Api key and not from the tutorial..

Comment: @PiyushGupta, i am using the latest Google play service.

Comment: Are you able to see map on ur real device?

Comment: @PiyushGupta, no... i see the same screen.

Comment: According to **Stephan Branczyk** add permission to manifest file.

Comment: try to Uninstall older app and built a new app

Comment: Can you check in the logcat if there is anything that might suggest an error once you see this screen? I mean, anything missing, wrong key, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated manifest use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ram.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="v3" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your api key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i have checked it out with your posted code, it is working to me, so i think, u need to check your api key and version, make sure you enable map v2 or v3

Answer (score 0):

You can only view it in a phone.
What you see now is all you can get in the Emulator.

Comment: No. i am viewing it in my phone. the screenshot is not from the emulator.

Comment: Have you "on" the status of "Google Maps Android API v2" service ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not asking for any of the gps permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Also since you're using fake locations, you might want to include this one as well. I don't know if it's relevant in this case, but just in case.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

Also, I know you said you're currently testing on a device, but for anyone who's curious about running google maps on an emulator (with the new Google Play dependency), it can be done [this way](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527).

Comment: i added those two permission. but still i see the same screen. no change.

Comment: I added one more permission, but I'm just grasping at straws at this point. Do make sure to rebuild your application (just in case the update didn't take). And make sure your phone has data/wifi enabled. From your screenshot, it looks very odd. It seems your phone has two cell network icons (one enabled, and one not)? That's weird. And no wifi enabled.

Comment: i added that permission, but still the same issue. ya i have my data and GPS enabled.

Comment: @ Stephan Branczyk, My device can have TWO Sim cards. But i use only one.

Comment: That's very cool. What model is that? Sorry I can't be of more help to your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the API-Key with your debug-keystore or do you sign the application with a another keystore to build for the device? The API-Key is bind to a keystore and must be changed if you sign with another keystore or another debug-keystore on another developer-machine.

Comment: I am using only one machine for my development. and i have generated the API KEY with my debug keystore.

Answer (score 0):

seems the guy who wrote about the permissions was right,
but I had the same problem and the solution was to correct the package name in the
internet site of google where you get the api key. 
because I built at the same day another project with almost the same package name,
and forgot I produced the api key with that project,it didn't work for me with the second project.